# Azure functions publish event to multiple event hubs with same event hub name but different connection string

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure function that listens to an Event hub trigger and based on the type of the message it forwards the events to one of the three target event hubs. The three target event hubs lie in different event hub namespace (thereby have different connection strings), however, the event hub name is same for all the three event hubs. This helps in easy access of the target event hubs by their consumers who have hard-coded the event hub name.

In order to create the event hub trigger and three listeners, I use the code below:

```
public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger(SourceEventHubName, Connection = SourceEventHubConnectionStringKey)] EventData[] events,
            [EventHub(TargetEventHubName, Connection = TargetEventHub1ConnectionStringKey)] IAsyncCollector<EventData> targetEventHub1,
            [EventHub(TargetEventHubName, Connection = TargetEventHub2ConnectionStringKey)] IAsyncCollector<EventData> targetEventHub2,
            [EventHub(TargetEventHubName, Connection = TargetEventHub3ConnectionStringKey)] IAsyncCollector<EventData> targetEventHub3,
            ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Above, I have used to same event hub name for the three target event hubs. However, when I run the azure function app it is observed that all the three output event hub parameters (targetEventHub1, targetEventHub2 and targetEventHub3) have the same event hub name and event hub connection string (the event hub connection string for the first event hub namespace is taken for all i.e. TargetEventHub1ConnectionStringKey) leading to all my events going to the same event hub namespace.

It appears that the Azure function SDK performs a grouping based on the event hub name for all the output IAsyncCollector and uses the connection string for the first element in the group.

Is there a way in Azure functions to target the events to three different event hub namespaces where the event hub name is the same.

Comment: where does it say it groups based on event hub name? Have you checked the trigger Configuration to make sure the Connection strings are different?

Comment: looks like it was a bug that was fixed some time ago https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/issues/6

Comment: Thanks @codebrane for highlighting the issue. The code fix for issue link provided appears to be coming when IAsyncCollector parameter does not have explicit EventHubName provided. In such case, the github code fix is fetching the event hub name from the connection string. Additionally, under the same code fix under GetEventHubClient method I see the response client being returned as "
if (_clients.TryGetValue(eventHubName, out client)) { return client;}}". So, it appears the grouping by event hub name is being made under this _client dictionary object.

Comment: For now I have used the separate event hub names to distinguish the event hubs. Appreciate any suggestion on how to publish to same event hub name but different namespace.